# GTK3 on MSYS2 segmentation fault on start

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm, msys2, gdk

I compiled the [basic GTK+ example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en) that just creates a window. When compiling the source code no errors occur. Also running it is fine. Note: For some reason it does not use the expected gnome style window appreance but rather the "normal" Windows 10 one. This might indicate that some dependencies are missing. (Also the gtk-demo-application has this look but not the gtk-demo or glade)

I set up my MSYS2 environment like described here https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/.
However I did `pacman -Syu` before and installed gtkmm3, cmake and ninja afterwards.

When using gdb to debug the programm a segmentation fault occurs.

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffb7c50c3c8 in lstrcpyA () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel32.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffb7c50c3c8 in lstrcpyA () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel32.dll
#1  0x000000018000e023 in WINTAB32!UpdateTaskBar () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinTab32.dll
#2  0x00000001800103ca in WTOpenW () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinTab32.dll
#3  0x000000018001052c in WTOpenW () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinTab32.dll
#4  0x0000000180010665 in WTOpenW () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinTab32.dll
#5  0x000000006c1f9ace in libgdk-3-0!gdk_win32_pixbuf_to_hicon_libgtk_only () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#6  0x0000000067f06c29 in libgobject-2.0-0!g_closure_invoke () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#7  0x0000000067f19ce9 in libgobject-2.0-0!g_signal_handler_disconnect () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#8  0x0000000067f243a7 in libgobject-2.0-0!g_signal_emit_valist () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#9  0x0000000067f24b78 in libgobject-2.0-0!g_signal_emit () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#10 0x0000000067f0ab93 in libgobject-2.0-0!g_cclosure_marshal_BOOLEAN__BOXED_BOXEDv () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#11 0x0000000067f0d04c in libgobject-2.0-0!g_object_notify () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#12 0x000000006c1cdf48 in libgdk-3-0!gdk_display_manager_open_display () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#13 0x0000000067f06e66 in libgobject-2.0-0!g_closure_invoke () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#14 0x0000000067f24743 in libgobject-2.0-0!g_signal_emit_valist () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#15 0x0000000067f253b9 in libgobject-2.0-0!g_signal_emit_by_name () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#16 0x000000006c1feaa9 in libgdk-3-0!gdk_win32_display_get_type () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#17 0x000000006c1cdd88 in libgdk-3-0!gdk_display_manager_open_display () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#18 0x000000006785b251 in libgtk-3-0!gtk_lock_button_set_permission () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#19 0x000000006785bba5 in libgtk-3-0!gtk_init () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#20 0x0000000063e4e81b in libgtkmm-3.0-1!_ZN3Gtk11ApplicationC1ERiRPPcRKN4Glib7ustringEN3Gio16ApplicationFlagsE () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtkmm-3.0-1.dll
#21 0x0000000063e4e8c1 in libgtkmm-3.0-1!_ZN3Gtk11Application6createERiRPPcRKN4Glib7ustringEN3Gio16ApplicationFlagsE () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtkmm-3.0-1.dll
#22 0x00000000004015bb in main (argc=1, argv=0x6cc3d0) at ../../../gtk-test/main.cc:6
(gdb)
```

The cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(gtk-test_sources 
    base.cc
)

# Use the package PkgConfig to detect GTK+ headers/library files
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtkmm-3.0)

# Setup CMake to use GTK+, tell the compiler where to look for headers
# and to the linker where to look for libraries
include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Add other flags to the compiler
add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable (gtk-test ${gtk-test_sources})
target_link_libraries(gtk-test ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```